# Which font has been used in this file that contains character components?

Tags: input-methods, character-components, fonts

This question is related to the Wubi input method, but mostly related to computer fonts, so you don't need to know how to use Wubi to be able to answer.

## Table of Contents

1. The context
2. The problem
3. Further information
4. The question

## The context

I have found [this repository](https://github.com/aardio/wubi-lex) in Github which contain some software for using Wubi, a shape-bsaed input method, in Windows. Within that repository, there's a [file](https://github.com/aardio/wubi-lex/blob/12463dad5a6e3d981c8d01c14c2fef0bb9b425e5/sepllingData/86.txt) [(archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20221031025618/https://github.com/aardio/wubi-lex/blob/12463dad5a6e3d981c8d01c14c2fef0bb9b425e5/sepllingData/86.txt) that list Chinese characters along with the Wubi components that are contained in those characters.

The following code block shows some lines from that file.

```
嘣   口山月月
垸   土宀二儿
蟋   虫丿米心
鄂   口口二阝
```

Below I provide an screenshot of those lines I shown above, for those users that might not have an approppiate font for the Chinese characters or the characters that show the Wubi components.

[image]

Sidenote: If you want to know more about Wubi, in [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wubi86_keyboard_layout.png) you can see the components on each key in the keyboard.

## The problem

When I open that file in my computer, there are some characters that are shown as unknown characters (i.e. a box with a code inside it). See screenshot below.

[image]

The lines that were shown in the screenshot above are shown in the code block below as text.

```
徭   彳爫山
孀   女木目
婆   氵又女
嘘   口七一
雏   ⺈彐亻
```

## Further information

I collected the characters that were shown as unknown characters in the whole file. The following code block contain those unique characters.

The unknown characters shown in the code block above are sorted according to their hexadecimal values (aka Unicode code or U+hex). The minimum hexadecimal value is F0000 (i.e. its Unicode code is U+F0000) and the maximum is F0157 (i.e. its Unicode code is U+F0157).

According to [this](https://unicode.org/glossary/#private_use_code_point) [(archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20221031040449/https://unicode.org/glossary/#private_use_code_point) document published by the Unicode Consortium, U+F0000..U+FFFFD is a range in the Unicode Standard for private use. This means that these characters cannot be considered as standardized characters in Unicode itself.

I think that the developer that created that file used a custom font to show the Wubi components for those characters that didn't have an equivalent Unicode character outside of the range for private use. However, I don't know which font it could be. I think a possible way to know the font, would be to ask the developer via email. If anyone is aware of another method for finding out that font, please let me know.

## The question

What font has glyphs for those unknown characters?

Comment: The released exe from the author displays the PUA characters correctly. It's too small to contain a Chinese font so I guess it's the default font on Windows.

Comment: I think it might be [AR PL UKai CN](https://fontinfo.opensuse.org/fonts/ARPLUKaiCNBook.html) or something similar ([example on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IdZP.png)).

Comment: I doubt it is; the 心s are clearly different, aren't they. Too bad. It's a very attractive typeface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the repository that you mentioned, there's [a file](https://github.com/aardio/wubi-lex/blob/master/lib/wubi/fonts.aardio) [(archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20221107001215/https://github.com/aardio/wubi-lex/blob/master/lib/wubi/fonts.aardio) called `fonts.aardio`. In the [line 31](https://github.com/aardio/wubi-lex/blob/12463dad5a6e3d981c8d01c14c2fef0bb9b425e5/lib/wubi/fonts.aardio#L31) of that file, the following is mentioned

```
install(.(ctrl,pxSize) = 安装字体到参数指定的控件\n字体参考 https://github.com/yanhuacuo/qingg 进行了增删修改\n大部分字根已改为普通文本
```

The translation of the Chinese characters into English is

> 字体参考 https://github.com/yanhuacuo/qingg 进行了增删修改\n大部分字根已改为普通文本

> Font reference https://github.com/yanhuacuo/qingg Added and deleted changes\n Most of the root characters have been changed to plain text

The repository whose URL was shown above contains a file called [`98WB-2.otf`](https://github.com/yanhuacuo/qingg/blob/master/98WB-2.otf) [(archive to download)](http://web.archive.org/web/20221107043500/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yanhuacuo/qingg/master/98WB-2.otf). If you download that file, and open the file using [fontforge](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q687332) (see screenshot below), you'll notice that the font defines glyphs for the hexadecimal values that you mentioned.

[image: screenshot of the software fontforge which confirms that the fonts indeed have glyphs for the characters that the original poster asked in this question]

Answer (score 0):

徭   彳爫  山

孀   is 女雨木目
https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%A8

婆   is just three parts  氵皮女

嘘   is just three parts  口七一

雏   is just three parts  ⺈彐亻
https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%BA%88

I accord to

http://www.wenqujingdian.com/Public/editor/attached/file/20180607/20180607180303_80199.pdf

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is about which font is used, not what the components are.

Comment: @Good-boy thanks for your explanation. As Ollie Linge mentioned, your reply doesn't answer the question. so it shouldn't have published as an answer.